# Identify Unlocked Device's Carrier

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, carriers

I bought an unlocked Samsung Galaxy S3 I9300 a while ago, this phone was imported by an independent store and not any of the local cellular carriers.

And my phone is not getting firmware updates, I suspect the carrier is not releasing the updates but I can't check it because I don't even know what carrier my phone is set to.

How can I tell what carrier my phone "belongs to"?

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy S3 I9300 is international version.
[image]

Look at the S3 variants.
S3 belongs to specific carrier has specific model numbers according to Country and Carrier.
Are you sure about it was an unlocked version??

Comment: I'm not sure about anything, both the Settings->Device Info screen and the sticker behind the battery say "GT-I9300", I didn't buy it from a cellular carrier or the official Samsung distributor so I assume it's a "gray market" unit. it got a firmware update once, my wife has the same model (bought from the same store but at a different time from a different shipment) and got 3 updates in the same time

Answer (score 0):

If you're adventurous and know your way around **Odin** (Samsung's firmware flashing tool), you can go [here](http://samsung-updates.com/device/?id=GT-I9300) to get the correct regional firmware for your S3. You can also download Odin from the same site and use it to manually flash your device with a new firmware. Doing it this way, the firmware you installed will be the "Vanilla / bare-bone" release from Samsung that does not have all the crap if you installed using a carrier's custom Android firmware.